# My jquery cookies are not resetting, even though am using the correct code

Tags: jquery, forms, cookies, reset

My problem is that I am trying to reset some form cookies so when someone has completed their form, they are reset so it is possible for someone else to complete the form. Simple and obvious.

But

However many different lines of code I put in, the cookies just do not seem to be disappearing. I am using the remember function from the site below:

[Komodo Media](http://www.komodomedia.com/blog/2008/07/using-jquery-to-save-form-details/)

So the details stay when they move away from the page: the code i have for the page starting is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function remember( selector ){
        $(selector).each(
            function(){

             //if this item has been cookied, restore it
            var name = $(this).attr('name');

            if( $.cookie( name ) ){
                if( $(this).is(':checkbox') ){
                    $(this).attr('checked',$.cookie( name ));
                }else{
                    $(this).val( $.cookie(name) );
                }

            }

            //assign a change function to the item to cookie it
            $(this).change(
                function(){
                    if( $(this).is(':checkbox') ){
                        $.cookie(name, $(this).attr('checked'), { path: '/', expires: 1 });
                    }else{

                        $.cookie(''+name+'', $(this).val(), { path: '/', expires: 1 });

                     }
            });
        });
}   
// JQUERY FOR THIS PAGE

$(document).ready( function(){
        remember("[name=username]"); 
    remember("[name=firstname]"); 
    remember("[name=lastname]"); 
    remember("[name=email]");
    remember("[name=password]"); 
    remember("[name=address1]"); 
    remember("[name=address2]"); 
    remember("[name=postcode]"); 
    remember("[name=country]");   
} );
</script>
```

And the code for resetting them is simple enough, as it takes the cookie name and sets it to null. However, this does not work as on returning to the form, all fields from before are still there.

Any help with this would be brilliant.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just the browser's default behavior? Check the cookies to be sure. Some user agents save form fields between page navigation.

Comment: i have checked the cookies, they are being stored in the jquery cookies.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a really simple answer. I managed to skip over the fact of cookies that expire and how they affect cookies.